# Exporting UV coords from Blender

Tags: blender, python, uv-mapping

So I have searched on google and various other websites but I've not found an answer. The only ones I did find did not work.

So my question is how do I get UV coords from blender (2.63)?

Currently I'm writing my own custom file exporter, and so far have managed to export vertices and their normals. Is there a way to export the UV coords?

N.B. I'm currently try to figure it out using a simple cube that is unwrapped and has a texture applied to it.

Comment: The .obj export script that comes with blender can do texture coordinates, you can find it in the scripts folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can export those. This is a bit of code I was using when I wrote a custom exporter:

```
 if len(mesh.uv_textures)>0:
    uvLayer=mesh.uv_textures.active
    uvLayer=uvLayer.data
    uv=uvLayer[faceIdx]
    uv=uv.uv1, uv.uv2, uv.uv3, uv.uv4
    uvCoord=uv[vertIndex][0], 1.0-uv[vertIndex][1]
    uvCoord=roundVec2(uvCoord)
else:
    uvCoord=v.uvco[0], 1.0-v.uvco[1]
    uvCoord=roundVec2(uvCoord)
```

Where `vertIndex` is enumerating over all the vertices in a face. And `faceIdx` is enumerating over all the faces in a mesh.

Then when writing:

```
file.write('u %.6f %.6f \n' %uvCoord) # uv
```

I should mention that I eventually abandoned the whole writing my own exporter. It's far easier to just write an importer that imports from a common export standard. This also has the additional benefit of your exporter being updated by someone else if Blender ever changes things.

Additionally, if you still want to write your own. Reading how it's done in the "official" exporters is a pretty big help.

For a larger picture of how this code is used:

```
class processVerts():
    def __init__(self, mesh, vert, face, faceIdx, vertIdx, file):
        ...
        def roundVec3(v):
            return round(v[0], 6), round(v[1], 6), round(v[2], 6)

        v=roundVec3(tuple(vert.co))
        ...
        if len(mesh.uv_textures)>0:
            uvLayer=mesh.uv_textures.active
            uvLayer=uvLayer.data
            uv=uvLayer[faceIdx]
            uv=uv.uv1, uv.uv2, uv.uv3, uv.uv4
            uvCoord=uv[vertIdx][0], 1.0-uv[vertIdx][1]
            uvCoord=roundVec2(uvCoord)
        else:
            uvCoord=v.uvco[0], 1.0-v.uvco[1]
            uvCoord=roundVec2(uvCoord)
        ...
        file.write('u %.6f %.6f \n' %uvCoord) # uv

class processFace():
    def __init__(self, mesh, face, faceIdx, file):
        ...
        for vertIdx, vert in enumerate(face.vertices):
                processVerts(mesh, meshVerts[vert], face, faceIdx, vertIdx, file)

class processMesh():
    def __init__(self, mesh, file):
        for faceIdx, face in enumerate(mesh.faces):
            processFace(mesh, face, faceIdx, file)
```

Comment: Couple of questions...
1. What is `faceIdx`? You say it enumerates over all the faces in the mesh, but how?
2. What is `v`? (inside the `else:` statement).

Comment: Does that edit answer your questions?

Comment: Not quite. Also to point out that `mesh.faces` does not work in Blender 2.63 but is `mesh.tessfaces` instead. So I'm trying to work around that.

Comment: Just one more reason to go with my alternative suggestion and just write an importer to work with one of the standard export formats. Also, the code I posted is old, yes, but that was just for the context. I thought you already had code that read vertices and normals?

Comment: Yes I do, but i don't understand why something like uv coords are readily available, like how normals are accessible through vertices, why not uv's through vertices too?

Also in the `file.write` part of your code, why does it have .6f? (Python is not my strong point).

Comment: I don't know why Blender did things that way. And `%.6f` writes a float with 6 digits after the decimal.

Comment: @Soapy If you found this answer helped you, can you accept it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yea thanks, your answer helped me understand it :) but now it not even writing the line to the file, so i suspect im missing something in the unwrapping proccess.